# Java UI Generator causing massive lag?

Tags: java, eclipse, performance, swing, netbeans

I am awful at Java GUI and used a generator to make most of the GUI for me. I made it in Netbeans and then copied it over to Eclipse. It lags out my pretty powerful computer for about 5 seconds on start and although I've tried timing it and stuff, I can't figure out why. I don't like to blame the generator but it is 100% coming from that UI code.

I would really appreciate someone helping me figure out what is causing it, and just in general improving the ugly UI code. The other code is unfinished, and this is just the interface part.

note that you can remove all of my code, even the gridLayout, and it will still lag, and if i compile it to a .jar and compile it with a -classpath argument it has the same lag

```
package ...

imports ...

public class x extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public x() {

        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        Point centrePoint = new Point(screenSize.width / 2, screenSize.height / 2);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);

        schMon = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        schTue = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        schWed = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        schThu = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        schFri = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        schSat = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        schSun = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        timeLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        schedulePanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        holdingPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        isEnabled = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
        dropboxPath = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        fileButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        saveButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        resetButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        sep2 = new javax.swing.JSeparator();
        sep = new javax.swing.JSeparator();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        schMon.setText("Monday");
        schTue.setText("Tuesday");
        schWed.setText("Wednesday       ");
        schThu.setText("Thursday");
        schFri.setText("Friday");
        schSat.setText("Saturday");
        schSun.setText("Sunday");
        Font font = new Font("Calibri", Font.BOLD, 13);
        timeLabel.setFont(font);
        timeLabel.setText("");
        schedulePanel.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
        schedulePanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(7, 24, -1, -1));

        schedulePanel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() { 
              public void mousePressed(MouseEvent mouseEvent) { 
                  //JPanel clickedPanel = (JPanel) getComponentAt(mouseEvent.getPoint());
                 // System.out.println(clickedPanel.getName().toString());
              } 
            }); 


        ArrayList<ArrayList<JPanel>> times = new ArrayList<ArrayList<JPanel>>();
        for (int day = 0; day < 7; day++) {
            times.add(new ArrayList<JPanel>());
            for (int hour = 0; hour < 24; hour++) {
                times.get(day).add(new JPanel());
                JPanel current = times.get(day).get(hour);
                current.setSize(42, 42);
                current.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
                current.setMaximumSize(current.getSize());
                current.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
                schedulePanel.add(current);
            }
        }


        holdingPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(2, 100));

        isEnabled.setText("Enable Scheduler");

        dropboxPath.setText("Path to your Dropbox.exe");
        dropboxPath.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        fileButton.setText("Find");
        fileButton.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(60, 22));

        saveButton.setText("Save");

        resetButton.setText("Reset");
        resetButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton3ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        sep2.setOrientation(javax.swing.SwingConstants.VERTICAL);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(
                holdingPanel);
        jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addComponent(isEnabled)
                    .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                    .addComponent(dropboxPath, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 480, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(fileButton, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(sep2, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(58)
                    .addComponent(saveButton)
                    .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(resetButton)
                    .addGap(2))
        );
        jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.TRAILING)
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(isEnabled, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(sep2, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(dropboxPath, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(fileButton, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(saveButton, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(resetButton, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addContainerGap())
        );
        holdingPanel.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(
                getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(layout
                .createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(
                        layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addContainerGap()
                                .addGroup(
                                        layout.createParallelGroup(
                                                javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                                .addComponent(sep)
                                                .addComponent(
                                                        holdingPanel,
                                                        javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
                                                        630, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                                .addGroup(
                                                        layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                                .addGroup(
                                                                        layout.createParallelGroup(
                                                                                javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                                                                .addComponent(
                                                                                        schSat)
                                                                                .addComponent(
                                                                                        schSun)
                                                                                .addComponent(
                                                                                        timeLabel)
                                                                                .addComponent(
                                                                                        schMon)
                                                                                .addComponent(
                                                                                        schTue)
                                                                                .addComponent(
                                                                                        schWed)
                                                                                .addComponent(
                                                                                        schThu)
                                                                                .addComponent(
                                                                                        schFri))
                                                                .addPreferredGap(
                                                                        javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                                                .addComponent(
                                                                        schedulePanel,
                                                                        javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
                                                                        javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
                                                                        Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                                .addContainerGap()));

        layout.setVerticalGroup(layout
                .createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(
                        layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addContainerGap()
                                .addGroup(
                                        layout.createParallelGroup(
                                                javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                                .addGroup(
                                                        layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                                .addGap(10)
                                                                .addComponent(
                                                                        schMon)
                                                                .addGap(30)
                                                                .addComponent(
                                                                        schTue)
                                                                .addGap(30)
                                                                .addComponent(
                                                                        schWed)
                                                                .addGap(30)
                                                                .addComponent(
                                                                        schThu)
                                                                .addGap(30)
                                                                .addComponent(
                                                                        schFri)
                                                                .addGap(30)
                                                                .addComponent(
                                                                        schSat)
                                                                .addGap(30)
                                                                .addComponent(
                                                                        schSun)
                                                                .addGap(12)
                                                                .addComponent(
                                                                        timeLabel)
                                                                .addGap(0,
                                                                        0,
                                                                        Short.MAX_VALUE))
                                                .addComponent(
                                                        schedulePanel,
                                                        javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
                                                        javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
                                                        Short.MAX_VALUE))
                                .addGap(10, 10, 10)
                                .addComponent(sep,
                                        javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                                        javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
                                        javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addGap(1, 1, 1)
                                .addComponent(holdingPanel,
                                        javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                                        45,
                                        javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)));

        pack();
        Point newLocation = new Point(centrePoint.x - (this.getWidth() / 2), centrePoint.y - (this.getHeight() / 2));
        setLocation(newLocation);
    }

    private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    }

    private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(javax.swing.UIManager
                    .getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(x.class.getName()).log(
                    java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(x.class.getName()).log(
                    java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(x.class.getName()).log(
                    java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(x.class.getName()).log(
                    java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new x().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private javax.swing.JButton fileButton;
    private javax.swing.JButton saveButton;
    private javax.swing.JButton resetButton;
    private javax.swing.JCheckBox isEnabled;
    private javax.swing.JLabel schMon;
    private javax.swing.JLabel schTue;
    private javax.swing.JLabel schWed;
    private javax.swing.JLabel schThu;
    private javax.swing.JLabel schFri;
    private javax.swing.JLabel schSat;
    private javax.swing.JLabel schSun;
    private javax.swing.JLabel timeLabel;
    private javax.swing.JPanel holdingPanel;
    private javax.swing.JSeparator sep;
    private javax.swing.JSeparator sep2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField dropboxPath;
    private javax.swing.JPanel schedulePanel;
}
```

Comment: Too much code. Please post a [SSCCE (link)](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Don't use UI generator

Comment: The code, once the imports are added, appears within a fraction of a second here using Java 6.something (couldn't be bothered checking).  I suspect something is wrong with the Eclipse environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the lag is during WindowBuilder's opening of the design page (parsing), the lag is normal.

[image]

Comment: it lags out, mouse wont move, then when the lag finishes that box pops up for a nanosecond and the program goes live

Comment: EDIT: if i compile it to a .jar and compile it with a -classpath argument it has the same lag